# DeclareMathDelimiter not working with Unicode font

Tags: luatex, unicode, delimiters

I am unable to get \DeclareMathDelimiter to work correctly with a Unicode font. I get the same results with XeLaTex and LuaLaTex. The custom font has a MATH table defined with both size variants and stretchy parts defined. Here is the example code

```
\documentclass[10pt,fleqn]{amsart}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\newfontface \logix {Logix.otf}[Scale=1.0,NFSSFamily=logix]

\DeclareSymbolFont{Logix}{TU}{logix}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathDelimiter{\OpnGrpX}{\mathopen}  {Logix}{"E301} {Logix}{"EBE0}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\ClsGrpX}{\mathclose} {Logix}{"E341} {Logix}{"EBF0}

\begin{document}

   \[ \left\OpnGrpX \frac{1}{2} \right\ClsGrpX \]

   \end{document}
```

and here is the generated output

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\DeclareMathDelimiter` uses the traditional TeX primitives `\delcode` or `\delimiter`. These accept a compact bitmap encoding both codepoints and the symbol families. This format only accepts codepoints up to 255, every else leads to odd behaviour because the additional digits leak into other fields of the bitmap.

So both XeTeX and LuaTeX support separate primitives for delimiters with higher codepoints: `\Udelcode` and `\Udelimiter`.
These only take a single codepoint, so instead of `E301` and `EBE0`, you only pass `E301`. It is the responsibility of the font to add `EBE0` to the linked list of bigger variants.

Then you get e.g.

```
\documentclass[10pt,fleqn]{amsart}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\newfontface \logix {Logix.otf}[Scale=1.0,NFSSFamily=logix]

\DeclareSymbolFont{Logix}{TU}{logix}{m}{n}

\makeatletter
\xdef\OpnGrpX{\Udelimiter\mathchar@type\mathopen\symLogix"E301 }
\xdef\ClsGrpX{\Udelimiter\mathchar@type\mathclose\symLogix"E341 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

   \[ \left\OpnGrpX \frac{1}{2} \right\ClsGrpX \]

\end{document}
```

`\Udelcode` could be used if you do not create a control sequence like `\OpnGrpX`, but want to make a character directly usable as a delimiter like `(` or `[`. For example, if you want `[` and `]` to use your new glyphs *iff they are used after `\left`, `\right` or similar*, you could use

```
\documentclass[10pt,fleqn]{amsart}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\newfontface \logix {Logix.otf}[Scale=1.0,NFSSFamily=logix]

\DeclareSymbolFont{Logix}{TU}{logix}{m}{n}

\Udelcode`\[\symLogix"E301
\Udelcode`\]\symLogix"E341

\begin{document}

   \[ \left[ \frac{1}{2} \right] \] -- Now uses the Logix glyphs

\end{document}
```

You could also e.g. use `\Udelcode"E301\symLogix"E301` to be able to type the Unicode character U+E301 after `\left`/`\right` directly.

(I would add a screenshot, but I would need the font first...)