# \Udelcode and \Udelimiter not working with Unicode font in LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, unicode-math, delimiters

I am unable to get the stretchy brackets \Udelcode with a Unicode font. I get the results in XeLaTex, but in LuaLaTex brackets are not stretched. I took the solution given by
[Marcel Krüger](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/493885/declaremathdelimiter-not-working-with-unicode-font) in this forum, the given solution worked only on XeLaTeX not LuaLaTeX

How to get the stretchy brackets for a custom font with `unicode-math.sty`

MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt,fleqn]{amsart}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\newfontface \logix {Logix.otf}[Scale=1.0,NFSSFamily=logix]

\DeclareSymbolFont{Logix}{TU}{logix}{m}{n}

\Udelcode`\[\symLogix"E301
\Udelcode`\]\symLogix"E341

\begin{document}

   \[ \left[ \frac{1}{2} \right] \] -- Now uses the Logix glyphs

\end{document}
```